# Rails 4 possible XSS error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, xss

I have a rails application with a basic shopping cart feature. Lately I've run into some problems when a user creates a cart. When they go to view the cart or update it (anything where we are presenting the Cart's line item properties), I get a weird error like this

```
I, [2016-10-20T22:13:50.962654 #28192]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms
F, [2016-10-20T22:13:50.965007 #28192] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong constant name <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>):
    21:         <% else %>
    22:           <td><%= line_item.object.line_itemable_type.titleize %></td>
    23:         <% end %>
    24:         <td><%= line_item.object.line_itemable.line_item_title.html_safe %></td>
    25:         <td style="text-align:right;"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.object.line_itemable.price) %></td>
```

Is this a sign of Cross-site scripting? I thought rails prevented that type of thing by default. The problem seems to be that when a user creates a new cart, the first item in the cart is always `<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>`. And after that the second item is the one they actually put in the cart. When they go to checkout or view cart, etc. it throws the above error because it tries to render that script. I've tried things to avoid rendering this but that doesn't fix the issue of *bad stuff in the cart*.

I've worked with rails for a few years now and have never encountered this problem (this is someone else's code I'm working on btw). Also, if I remove the first line item (with the script tags) from the cart, everything is fine and user can update or complete order. Where do I begin trying to fix this and prevent it from happening again?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Judging from the `ActionView::Template::Error` I'd say that the `<script>alert...` is at someplace it shouldn't, or it's not escaped properly. Hard to tell without some actual code.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasR.Koll. Not sure what code to show here. Nowhere in my codebase do I have `<script>alert...`. It is getting inserted somehow.